# Is this a tricky solution to subclass Arrays?

Tags: javascript

Today working on a new SVG framework I'm doing I try to subclass arrays to work with nodes... and after a few hours I finish with this code (I only tested over Safari):

```
customArray=function(){
    // Do the thing
    this.__proto__= Array.prototype;

    // Add some prototypes to the main customArray
    this.f1=function(){console.log(1)}; // f1 custom function
    this.f2=function(){console.log(2)}; // f2 custom function
};

newCustomArray=new customArray();
newCustomArray.f3=function(){console.log(3)}  // f3 function only for newCustomArray

console.log(newCustomArray instanceof Array); // true
console.log([] instanceof Array);             // true
console.log("---------------------"); 
console.log(newCustomArray.f1);               // function(){console.log(1)};
console.log(newCustomArray.f2);               // function(){console.log(2)};
console.log(newCustomArray.f3);               // function(){console.log(3)};
console.log([].f1);                           // undefined
console.log([].f2);                           // undefined
console.log([].f3);                           // undefined
console.log("---------------------");
console.log(newCustomArray.forEach);          // Native function
console.log([].forEach);                      // Native function
```

For me is working but as "system" says **proto** is not everywhere.

Comment: `.__proto__` is non-standard, so it depends on which environments you're supporting.

Comment: You can't "subclass" Array because an object made via `new` is just a plain object (i.e. instance of Object), only real arrays have the special self–adjusting length property. Simply setting an object's `[[Prototype]]` to `Array.prototype` will only get you the methods.

Comment: Oh, you've also discovered the uselessness of `instanceOf`. It does not tell you what an object is actually an instance of, only whether it has a constructor property somewhere on its inheritance chain that references the supplied object.

Comment: @RobG: No. The "constructor" property still has nothing to do with [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Comment: @Bergi—yes, my bad. Getting `true` from `x instanceof X` doesn't guarantee that X constructed `x` (i.e. that `x` is an instance of `X`), only that `X.prototype` is on `x`'s `[[Prototype]]` chain.

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not want the `CustomArray` constructor to be an Array (have array methods). What would be relevant is this:

```
newCustomArray instanceof Array; // false, should be true
newCustomArray.forEach; // undefined, should be [].forEach
```

Read on [How ECMAScript 5 still does not allow to subclass an array](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/). Both properties above are easy to implement, but the actual problem is the `length` property (which does not work for your `newCustomArray` as well).

Comment: Yeha you are true, seams I misktake my var names hahaha (sh*t)

Answer (score 0):

Following with a way to get something similar to a subclass Array I try this and for me is ok not the best, but usable.

What you think?

http://jsfiddle.net/microbians/837rv/

```
    listOfCustomArrays   =[];
    listOfCustomArrays.fn={};
    Array_prototype=Array.prototype;

    Array=function(){

        // Add a new custom array to the list
        listOfCustomArrays.push([]); // NEW ARRAY
        listOfCustomArrays[listOfCustomArrays.length-1].index=listOfCustomArrays.length-1;

        // The the current last
        var arr=listOfCustomArrays[listOfCustomArrays.length-1];

        for (j in listOfCustomArrays.fn) {
            Object.defineProperty(arr, j, {
                value: listOfCustomArrays.fn[j]
            });
        }

        return arr
    };

    Array.extend=function(name,fnc) {
        listOfCustomArrays.fn[name]=fnc;
        for (i=0; i<listOfCustomArrays.length; i++) {
            Object.defineProperty(listOfCustomArrays[i], name, {
                value: listOfCustomArrays.fn[name]
            });
        }
    }

    Array.prototype=Array_prototype;

    newCustomArray=new Array();

    //Array.extend('f1', function(){console.log(1)} );
    Array.prototype.f1=function(){console.log('f1:prototyped')};

    Array.extend('f2', function(){console.log('f2:extended')} );
    Array.extend('f3', function(){console.log('f3:extended')} );

    newCustomArray2=new Array();
    Array.extend('f4', function(){console.log('f4:extended')} );

    console.log(typeof Array);
    console.log(typeof []);
    console.log("---------------------");
    console.log(newCustomArray.f1);
    console.log(newCustomArray.f2);
    console.log(newCustomArray.f3);
    console.log(newCustomArray.f4);
    console.log("---------------------");
    console.log(newCustomArray2.f1);
    console.log(newCustomArray2.f2);
    console.log(newCustomArray2.f3);
    console.log(newCustomArray2.f4);
    console.log("---------------------");
    console.log([].f1);
    console.log([].f2);
    console.log([].f3);
    console.log([].f4);
    console.log("---------------------");
    console.log(newCustomArray.forEach);
    console.log(newCustomArray2.forEach);
    console.log([].forEach);
    console.log(Array.prototype.forEach);
```